# Platforms or Frameworks or Tools for responsive java web app development

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

We have developed a native Android application. We want to develop new responsive web application having similar look and feel as native app, so that users don't have much different experience between two applications. Are there any recommended programming languages to develop the web app. We were thinking of developing a Spring MVC based application using HTML5 and jQuery, bootstarp. Any recommendations will be helpful. The application has to consume a SOAP service as well.

Answer (score 0):

• For backend Server side - Spring MVC through Spring boot will be a good option as it speeds up the development process. Springboot will take care most of the configurations.

• For frontend client side - Angular would be a good option rather than jQuery.
Angular is a framework for client side coding. It has many built in services that is be easy for development, testing and deployment.